# SQL Query using a function to select data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What is the best way of writing an sql query that calls a user defined function as part of the query before produce the selected output. i.e. I want to do something like below please where I the user defined function does some calculations on the table data.

```
select field1, field2 from table1 where function(table1.field3, table1.field4) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Your (scalar) function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_function (@a AS int, @b AS int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    RETURN @a * @b
END
```

Your query:

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM table1
WHERE dbo.my_function(table1.field3, table1.field4) > 10
```

Don't forget the `dbo` in `dbo.my_function`. It is required for user defined scalar functions.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure may play well or just to write a math/string condition. Depends on how complicated is your condition.

Comment: Stored procedures are not allowed there.